# Is it possible to tweak an existing template instead of replacing it?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I'm trying to style some buttons in Wpf. The only thing I actually want to change is the colours used for the hover/click/focused effects.

All the tutorials I've found rely on replacing the template for the button entirely. This is great if you want to change everything about the button; However, if all you want to do is change some colours it's a monumental undertaking to reimplement properly.

The default control gives a lot of functionality for free (animations, [UI automation/accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742153.aspx), tested in multiple localisations, etc). Making it look like the original is tedious enough, but making it function the same way is near impossible.

So... Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, is it possible to load the default template, modify it and then apply the modified version? Doing this in xaml as opposed to C# would be preferable.

Comment: Are the colours bound or hardcoded?

Comment: @JohanLarsson If they could be bound, that would be ideal but hard coded is sufficient. I don't currently need them to change at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a few years ago, and I came up with [this solution](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/10/01/wpf-creating-parameterized-styles-with-attached-properties/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really useful article and I'll keep it for future reference, but I don't think it solves my current problem - eg they have to modify their own custom template to take the parameters. In this case, I would need to modify the default template and it doesn't discuss that...

Comment: @Basic, you can just edit the default template; the XAML designer provides an option to do that.

Comment: I didn't know that feature existed. You've just made Wpf far more enjoyable, thank you.